# Why does the magnitude of the force determine how fast momentum changes and not how much?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum

Why does the magnitude of the force determine how fast momentum changes and not how much?

I thought since net force $= dp/dt$ so $\Delta p = F \Delta t$ which affects the magnitude of change of momentum, but apparently it denotes how fast it changes.

Comment: $F = \frac {\Delta p}{\Delta t}$ and $\Delta p = F \Delta t$ are both correct if the force $F$ is constant. Can you explain your source of confusion more clearly ?

Comment: If you and I both have... say,... bowling balls, and we both push _for the same amount of time,_ then if I push mine twice as hard as you push yours during that time interval, then I will give mine twice as much momentum as you gave to yours. But that's precisely _because_ I was changing the momentum of mine during that time interval as you were changing the momentum of yours.

Comment: Are you thinking of impulse?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_(physics)

Comment: You can apply 100 N of force for 2 seconds, and it will impart the same change in momentum to the object as a 50 N force would in 4 seconds. So the force magnitude is indeed a measure of how quickly momentum changes in an object subjected to that force.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you push with the same force for a longer time, it has more effect.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/418030)

Comment: @MaximalIdeal Of course it provides an answer. What's missing?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is just how one decides to look at Newton's second law. It is indeed the case that $ F(t) = dp/dt $ describes how fast the momentum is changing, as it states that an applied force is proportional to the rate of change of momentum.

However, integrating both sides, $ \Delta p = \int dp = \int F(t) dt $ (which is equivalent to $ \Delta p = F \Delta t $, if $ F $ is a constant in time) states that the total change in momentum is proportional to force multiplied by the time interval.

Your two equations are technically expressing two different things. One of them states a rate of change of momentum, one of them states a total change in momentum. Is this so unusual, though? If you express some quantity "X per second" and then multiply by seconds, you just get X.

Answer (score 1):

Force indeed determines *how fast* momentum changes, and if you also consider a time interval, by integrating the force function on it, you will obtain *how much* momentum changes.